# MYSQL formular una pequeña consulta

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

espero que esten muy bien. A ver si por favor me podran ayudar con MYSQL!

Tengo la siguiente Consulta:

```
SELECT cambio_id,
   estado_id, 
   cambio_id as ultimoCambio,
   estado_id as ultimoEstado,
   lote_pedido
     FROM 
     cambios_registrados
     WHERE estado_id in (1,2,3) AND lote_pedido = 73722
```

Me devuelve los siguientes registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que me muestre un solo registro (al agregar el limit 1 funciona pero en ultimoCambio y ultimoEstado deberia ver los ultimos agregados) en este caso deberia ser el siguiente:

```
cambio_id // estado_id // ultimoCambio // ultimoEstado // lote_pedido

-----407--//----- 3---// ------410----// -------2 ----//----73722-----
```

alguna idea de como hacerlo? Saludos

Comment: Si lo que necesitas es mostrar solo una línea puedes usar `limit`, al final de tu query pon `limit 1`.

Comment: Si, pero al usar el limit 1, sigo viendo como ultimoCambio el 407, y ultimoEstado el 3. Y deberia verlo como puse un poco mas abajo

Comment: ¿Necesitas el `cambio_id` en tu consulta? Con las ediciones pareciera que quieres el último cambio y el último estado del lote_pedido seleccionado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ver la información del último id generado ordena de forma descendente y ponle límite a 1

```
SELECT cambio_id,
  estado_id, 
  cambio_id as ultimoCambio,
  estado_id as ultimoEstado,
  lote_pedido
FROM 
  cambios_registrados
  WHERE estado_id in (1,2,3) AND lote_pedido = 73722
ORDER BY cambio_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Si sólo quieres ver el 407 o sea el primero pero ver los máximos, mejor agrupa

```
SELECT cambio_id,
  MIN(estado_id) as estado_id, 
  MAX(cambio_id) as ultimoCambio,
  MAX(estado_id) as ultimoEstado,
  lote_pedido
FROM 
  cambios_registrados
  WHERE estado_id in (1,2,3) AND lote_pedido = 73722
GROUP BY lote_pedido
```

Espero que te de una idea.